# PC to PC communication using USB

Tags: java, usb

Is it possible to send data over USB from one PC to another?

If yes, I want to transfer a bit stream from one machine to another over USB cable. Is there any java library which I can use? I found out [usb4j](http://kayahr.github.io/usb4java/). Would it do me any good?

I read [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/342-connecting-two-computers-with-a-usb-cable) that it will 'fry' the USB controllers in my PC! 
Why is it so?

EDIT1: USB here means NOT thumb drives, rather the USB cables.

Comment: Put your USB in a PC. Copy the data from the PC to your USB. Remove the USB. Put it in another PC. Copy the data from the USB to this PC.

Comment: I think he meant directly...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he's not talking about a usb drive.  He's talking about a cable connecting the two machines together.  A non-ethernet networking solution

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @RussellUhl I know, just being sarcastic :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah ok.  in that case: lol :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a TRUE usb A to A cable (in production), as no p2p protocol exists for USB hubs to talk to one another, and it is not a hemaphroditic connection, so this cable would be worthless. All A to A cables include some sort of controller.

Every A to A "cable" I have ever encountered has a controller in the middle that either:

Makes a network connection similar to what was described in your article

Uses some Proprietary software solution (sometimes emulating a mass storage device)

However, if you were to make an A to A cable, it **might** fry it, and theoretically could, as you would be sending power to both ends, but i seriously doubt it would happen since it's only 500mA. other than that, it wouldn't do anything

Comment: Erm, you can buy any number of USB "data transfer" cables which is exactly what is required (and yes, putting power to power with a straight through cable will "fry" at least one end). The fact that they come with their own software to make it so you don't have to write your own ... really doesn't matter. It's a crossover cable, and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: its not just a cable. it includes a USB to Network controller.

Comment: So, in short, I cannot use a USB A to A cable to transfer data from one machine to another unlike a serial port?

Comment: @VineetMenon in short, yes USB is not a hemaphroditic connection. And there is no such thing as a TRUE A to A cable.
I can't think of a full-duplex 2-way digital connection that is. Most people get confused because network ports have learned to auto switch without a crossover cable.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you need a special cable.  I'd have to look at the wiring diagrams but it's something like both machines would try to feed power into the cable, thereby frying the other end of the circuit.  I believe it is a similar reason as to why you can't do the same thing with an ethernet cable (unless it's a crossover cable): the controllers are expecting data on the wrong pins.

Is there a particular reason you want to do this, or is this a theoretical question?

Answer (score -2):

Dear you use USB data cable but in some cases its not working .

but if you have a LAN cable then you can simply create a connection between both system and can transfer data up to 100 Mbps. its frequent data transfer method .

Comment: There's nothing specific in your answer. It is really the fault of the question, because it is so vague. Best to leave such questions alone. or, use the comments, not an answer.